# Parallel processing in R - AMD Bulldozer

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to set up a "socket cluster" to perform some computations in R my home desktop (random forest imputation with the missForest package). However, I have the AMD 8150 processor. I'm clueless with regards to the modules concept with the processor. Is it better to set up four processes or eight (I'm assuming eight?)

Comment: Theoretically, eight must be at least as good as four, since you could always keep the other four idle...

Comment: This sounds like it's related to Intel Hyperthreading.  On current Intel, leaving (the right) four cores idle is as good as having only four.  Older Intel is penalized for enabling Hyperthreading in various ways, depending on the age.  But in any case, this question is not for this site.  Super User, perhaps?